# Ingress controller NodePort not reachable from outside

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a cluster of 3 vm on which I install kubernetes and deployed some pods and services that I would like to be accessible from outside (my local pc for exemple)

I followed this tutorial https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal to install my ingress controller.
I have created a service of type NodePort.
I have created a ingress that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.service.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 9090
```

`kubectl get svc myservice` gives me:

```
NAME        TYPE       CLUSTER-IP        EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
myservice   NodePort   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   <none>        9090:31220/TCP   47m
```

`kubectl get ingress test-ingress` gives me

```
NAME            HOSTS            ADDRESS          PORTS   AGE
test-ingress    my.service.com   xx.xxx.xxx.xxx   80      49m
```

On my local computer I have added to /etc/hosts I have mapped the ip address of the ingress to the name my.service.com
When I try to ping my.service.com or directly the ip I go request timeout 100% packet loss.
I tried to reach my service visual interface with the web browser and it does not work either.

How can I investigate further why I can't access to my service from outside the cluster ?

Comment: Can you hit the `NodeIP:NodePort` ?

Comment: Yes I can hit NodeIP:NodePort, but not using the name I gave inside the ingress file.

Comment: Its most probably a firewall issue i guess. Check your firewall settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably an issue with your firewall. Check the firewall rules if they are blocking access from outside to that port.

Also you should access the service from the NodePort of the service you created while deploying the ingress controller.

Also edit your ingress and add the tls and hosts property with a self signed certificate for `my.service.com`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
      ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my.service.com
    secretName: tls-secret-for my service
  rules:
  - host: my.service.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 9090
```

Comment: Firewalls are deactivated on all nodes.  I will try with tls and hosts property, thank you for the example.

Comment: Sure and also to create the tls secret use `kubectl create secret generic <name> --from-file=tls.crt=<path to .crt file> --from-file=tls.key=<path to .key file> -n <namespace>`.
Just in case if you needed to know the structure of the secret.

Comment: Hey @jerome so was tls the issue? Let us know so that future visitors could easily get it.

Comment: no it is not the certificate. I still have the problem to access it from the browser at my.service.com

Comment: Is nginx showing any error when accessing from the browser or is it just a timeout?

Comment: Maybe it is my mapping in /etc/hosts that is not good.  I the ip of ingress to my.service.com, shouldn't it be the mapped to NodeIP:NodePort instead ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208195/discussion-between-rohan-mehto-and-jerome).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to `ping` a Kubernetes service IP.

IP for services are virtual IP, thus they are not pingable.
To test you ingress, you should try to reach your service with `curl` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to curl with a host header set to www.my.service.com

```
curl --verbose --header 'Host: www.my.service.com' http://nodeip:nodeport/
```

Comment: Indeed the curl works.  Now how can I access it from my browser using my.service.com